# Jetted tub plastic tube

Tags: bathtub, jetted

I have a jetted tub that started leaking, I have an access panel and was able to find the issue of a bad gasket. I also noticed a small plastic tube that was not connected. I'm not clear where this should reconnect to. See images below, any help here?

[image]

Comment: What is the tube connected to at the other end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that should connect to the on/off push button for your tub. It operates a pneumatic switch. Maybe you pulled it loose when you were in there.

Comment: there should be a little nub/pipe end somewhere around the perimeter where the tube ends that it will re-attach to. If not, and the buttons all work, then it's safe to leave as-is without leaking anything.